# "Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path" exception in spring MVC when submitting the form a third time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form with a checkbox "genererCle" and a list "cadre". When the user select another value in the list or if he check/unchecks the checkbox there is a server invokation. It's defined between 2 files : topologie.html and topologie.js  :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/bus/topologie}"
            th:object="${topologie}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
...
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{genererCle}"
            th:value="${genererCle}" class="genererCle" />
    </div>
    <select th:field="*{versionCadre}" class="form-control">
        <option th:each="versionCadre : ${allVersionCadre}"
            th:value="${versionCadre}" th:text="${versionCadre}">...</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" hidden="hidden" id="updateNatures"
        name="updateNatures"></button> 
    <button type="submit" hidden="hidden" id="genererCle"
        name="genererCle"></button>
```

The .js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
    $("#versionCadre").change(function() {
        $("#updateNatures").click();
    });
    $(".genererCle").change(function() {
        $("#genererCle").click();
    });
...
}
```

On the server side it's working with a controller, TopologieController, in which I have defined 2 methods :

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = "topologie", types = { Topologie.class })
@RequestMapping("/bus/topologie")
public class TopologieController {
    private static final String VIEW_TOPOLOGIE = "topologie";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "genererCle" })
    public String genererCle(final Topologie topologie, final Model model)
        throws IOException {
        cadreService.genererCle(topologie);
        return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "updateNatures" })
    public String updateNatures(final Topologie topologie, final Model model)
        throws IOException {
        cadreService.updateConfig(topologie);
        return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validForm(final Topologie topologie,
        final BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr,
        HttpSession session) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            logger.info("Form has errors ! : {}", result);
            return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE;
        }

        attr.addFlashAttribute("topologie", topologie);
        return "redirect:/bus/topologie/recap";
    }
```

Each submit works fine independantly but when I do 3 submits consecutively I have an exception. The submit sequence : The user changes the value in the list "versionCadre" then he checks the "genererCle" checkbox and finally he makes another change in the list "versionCadre".

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8081/bus/topologie': {public java.lang.String fr.cnamts.navigo.web.TopologieController.updateNaturesPost(fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.Topologie,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.io.IOException, public java.lang.String fr.cnamts.navigo.web.TopologieController.genererClePost(fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.Topologie,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.io.IOException}
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:375) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:322) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:60) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:351) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1120) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:243) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]

2016-06-08 12:27:55.810  WARN 9868 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Relevant informations in the HTTP Request :

> Request Headers :
>
> Request URL:http://localhost:8081/bus/topologie Request Method:POST
>   Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed Remote Address:[::1]:8081
>
> Form Data :
>
> versionCadre:RP030600V genererCle:true
>   _genererCle:on updateNatures:

I thought that the param naming (java side) was clear. But when I read similar questions here I understand that it's not enough.

I've try to use the  PR(G) pattern changing this :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "genererCle" })
public String genererCle(final Topologie topologie, final Model model)
    throws IOException {
    cadreService.genererCle(topologie);
    return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE;
}
```

In this :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "genererCle" })
public String genererClePost(final Topologie topologie, final Model model)
        throws IOException {
    cadreService.genererCle(topologie);
    return "redirect:/bus/topologie";
}
```

But it doesn't work better.

Comment: How often are you going to ask this question (you removed the previous one with exact the same content). The answer was already on that question and the error is in your view not your mappings.

Comment: It's not the same content, I add the answer to the first one talking about the PRG solution. I ask it in a new question because the answer to the first one doesn't work and a new question has more chance to have an answer than a comment in an old one. And I deleted the old one in order to not do a duplicate.

Comment: Instead of asking the same question and additional problems I suggest doing a tutorial and check how spring mvc works. As the main issue is that you don't understand how it works.

Comment: Indeed I think I don't understand it deeply enough. But you're wrong if you think I did not search before asking. I've read many tutorials and look for an answer before asking it here. But if you have a tutorial that could help me understand the underlying concept I miss here, I'll be glad to read it ;-)

Comment: a redirect is a new request, which means yo need to retrieve the reference data etc. again. This is something that should be done in the GET method for the topology view, this is something you already should have.

Comment: Thanks, in my case the topology is not stored at this point, everything is in the request. So I can't use the PRG pattern here.

Comment: Why not, store it as flash attribute. Instead of thinking what you cannot do look at what the framework can do. Also if this is all in the same controller, you can simply store the thing in the session in between requests.

Comment: I've stored the topologie object in the session, that part works fine, thanks. But I still have the "ambiguous request mapping" exception at the third post request, even with the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar error.

In the controller I had 2 methods like these.

1. ```
   @RequestMapping(value = { "/{name}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   void foo1(@PathVariable("name") final String name)
   ```
2. ```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/{email}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    void getTemplateVersionsBySenderForClient(@PathVariable("email") final String email,
            @RequestParam(value = "timestamp", required = true) final long timestamp)
   ```

then I changed the request mapping part for the second method:

`@RequestMapping(value = { "/trigger/{email}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)`

And the error was resolved.

Concept was, from the front end side Spring mvc was not able to decide for which method needs to be called. As both `{name}` and `{email}` in the requestMapping were variables.
http://localhost:8000/Project/{email} and http://localhost:8000/Project/{name} both email and name can take similar values(not validating)

Hope it helps

Comment: The same concept is very much valid in case where we have controller and the parent controller class. Then it will check for the unique request mapping in the combination of all the request mapping for the controller and the parent controller.

Comment: If I wanted to catch the error, what is the error type?

Comment: Return type should not vary, actually exception should be handled a step before the request leaves controller.
In case it is unhandled, some cool inbuild stuffs come handy in frameworks. 
Like spring framework, provide ResponseEntity<T>, T can be any entity. It can be build to handle errors. 
If we are using swagger, we can just annotate the controller method with

_@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message = "Invalid request."),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, message = "Unauthorized access") })_

Comment: I'm not asking about HTTP status codes. I want to `try` and `catch` the error. What is the class of the error?

Comment: For try and catch you should be doing this before sending the control to controller itself. Java provide Exception base class, you can always create you custom exception handling class. For specific answer please post the specific questions along with the code and dependencies you are using to build it.